# SIP call error file JNI android

Tags: android, c++

```
/*
     * Recieve data on the connected socket into the specified buffer. The
     * packet fields <code>data</code> & <code>length</code> are passed in
     * addition to <code>packet</code> to eliminate the JNI field access
     * calls.
     * 
     * @param aFD the socket FileDescriptor @param packet the DatagramPacket to
     * receive into @param data the data buffer of the packet @param offset the
     * offset in the data buffer @param length the length of the data buffer in
     * the packet @param receiveTimeout the maximum length of time the socket
     * should block, reading @param peek indicates to peek at the data @return
     * number of data received @exception IOException upon an read error or
     * timeout
     */
    static native int recvConnectedDatagramImpl(FileDescriptor aFD,
            DatagramPacket packet, byte[] data, int offset, int length,
            int receiveTimeout, boolean peek)  ;

    static native int recvConnectedDatagramDirectImpl(FileDescriptor aFD,
            DatagramPacket packet, int address, int offset, int length,
            int receiveTimeout, boolean peek)  ;

    /*
     * Send the <code>data</code> to the nominated target <code>address</code>
     * and <code>port</code>. These values are derived from the
     * DatagramPacket to reduce the field calls within JNI.
     * 
     * @param fd the socket FileDescriptor @param data the data buffer of the
     * packet @param offset the offset in the data buffer @param length the
     * length of the data buffer in the packet @param port the target host port
     * @param bindToDevice if bind to device @param trafficClass the traffic
     * class to be used when the datagram is sent @param inetAddress address to
     * connect to. @return number of data send
     * 
     * @exception IOException upon an read error or timeout
     */
    static native int sendDatagramImpl(FileDescriptor fd,
            byte[] data, int offset, int length, int port,
            boolean bindToDevice, int trafficClass, InetAddress inetAddress)
             ;

    static native int sendDatagramDirectImpl(FileDescriptor fd,
            int address, int offset, int length, int port,
            boolean bindToDevice, int trafficClass, InetAddress inetAddress)
             ;

    /*
     * Send the <code>data</code> to the address and port to which the was
     * connnected and <code>port</code>.
     * 
     * @param fd the socket FileDescriptor @param data the data buffer of the
     * packet @param offset the offset in the data buffer @param length the
     * length of the data buffer in the packet @param bindToDevice not used,
     * current kept in case needed as was the case for sendDatagramImpl @return
     * number of data send @exception IOException upon an read error or timeout
     */
    static native int sendConnectedDatagramImpl(FileDescriptor fd,
            byte[] data, int offset, int length, boolean bindToDevice)
             ;

    static native int sendConnectedDatagramDirectImpl(FileDescriptor fd,
            int address, int offset, int length, boolean bindToDevice)
             ;
```

Comment: improved format in your question please.

Comment: Why can not receive calls? What are the problems

Comment: I don't know... i can't see your errors/problems... If you don't post anything we can't help you.... sorry.